What is the correct way to send a captcha check request to hcaptcha?
I'm trying to bypass the new Discord captcha “Drag Drop”. I found a utility to solve this captcha via opencv, it solves the captcha correctly.
host = "discord.com"
site_key = "a9b5fb07-92ff-493f-86fe-352a2803b3df"
motion = motion_data(headers["User-Agent"], f"https://{host}")
motiondata = motion.get_captcha()

def Get_Captcha(host, sitekey, n, req):
        try:
            json = {
                "sitekey": sitekey,
                "v": "d136a52",
                "host": host,
                "n": n,
                'motionData': motiondata,
                "hl": "en",
                "c": dumps(req)
            }

            data = urllib.parse.urlencode(json)
            r = httpx.post(f"https://api.hcaptcha.com/getcaptcha/{sitekey}",data=data, headers=headers, timeout=4)

            return r.json()
        except Exception as e:
            return False

def Solve_Captcha(host, sitekey, n, req, res):
            captcha = {
                "request_type": res['request_type'],
                "tasklist": res['tasklist']
            }
            
            inst = DragDrop(captcha, verbose=False)
            solved_captcha = inst.solve()
            print(solved_captcha)
            print("\n")
            
            
            
            json = {
                "answers": solved_captcha,
                "c": dumps(req),
                "job_mode": res['request_type'],
                'motionData': motion.check_captcha(),
                "n": n,
                "serverdomain": host,
                "sitekey": sitekey,
                "v": "d136a52",
            }
            print(f"json: {json}\n")

            data = urllib.parse.urlencode(json)
            r = httpx.post(f"https://api.hcaptcha.com/checkcaptcha/{sitekey}/{res['key']}", data=data, headers=headers, timeout=4)
            print(f"r: {r}")

            return r.json()

def bypass(sitekey, host):
        req = REQ_Data(sitekey=sitekey, host=host)
        req["type"] = "hsl"
        print(f"req: {req}")
        n = N_Data(req["req"])
        print(f"ndata: {n}")
        res = Get_Captcha(sitekey=sitekey, host=host,n=n, req=req)
        print(f"res: {res}\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        
        solved_captcha = Solve_Captcha(sitekey=sitekey, host=host,n=n, req=req, res=res)
        print(solved_captcha)
   
bypass(site_key, host)

When sending a hcaptcha check request, it gives an error 'invalid-answers', but answers looks correct
If the answers were incorrect, I would get a different form with the value pass: False
I've tried changing motionData generators, tried inserting my own, tried using hsw instead of hsl (I couldn't find a working one), but nothing helped.
Get_Captcha output
Solve_Captcha output

What would you consider the "correct way" of doing something where the receiver is designed to not allow exactly that?
